# Is Android Webview is same as the Chrome browser?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having the webview, which will be created using the following code.

```
  WebView mWebView=new WebView(this);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());       
  mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidJavaInterface(), "JavaInterface");
```

Is this webview is same as the chrome.? If I am loading any URL into this webview using loadurl() method, and running in two different devices, Is the webview is same in all the devices?. I think it will run on the customized mWebView or Is the app pick the device's default browser for loading URL?

EDIT 1: I have created the webview in android version 2.2. That is API 8. If I am running the app in android 4.1 device. Is the webview version is changed or the webview is remain same for all the devices with different versions?

Comment: If there is no other web browser present in the device then it will launch device default browser and that is not chrome but the web browser designed for android itself. And there is any other browser present then it will show a dialog to make a choice from.

Answer (score 0):

No, Webview widget is not Chrome.

Comment: If the webview is created using the target 8,Is the webview version is changed according to the target device, that is,If I am running the app in various different versions of android devices.?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a WebView adding some behaviour like Javascript and Java, but IT WILL NEVER BE LIKE A BROWSER (less performance,less capability...).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see the Edit1 in my query.

Comment: The WebView in an Android 4.1 device may be better and have new methods but if you build your app for API 8 you can't use those features

Comment: Yes, I can't use those features. If I am creating the webview in Android version 2.2 and run the same in Android devices with different versions(2.3,3.1,4.0,4.1).Is the webview versions is changed on the different version devices.?

Answer (score 0):

Well according to my knowledge WebView and Chrome browser are different.

WebView is an Android widget which is used to display local and remote web pages. Even though it has got some features of a browser like rendering JavaScript, it cannot be considered as a fully fledged browser.

Please refer [Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see the EDIT 1.